# IllegalStateException: 403 error on Sonarcube via VPN

Tags: sonarqube, vpn

Sonarcube server is behind our company VPN server. If I connect to VPN, I can access sonar in browser without any issues. But while connecting from sonarCLI or IntelliJ plugin getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
        ... 155 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Status returned by url [https://sonarqube.ourtesco.com/batch/index] is not valid: [403]
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:118)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
        ... 158 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a proxy while connecting to the server solved the issue.

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you do that?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I have used proxy option in IntelliJ, see the updated answer.